# Maximum .NET version for Coldfusion 8 interop?

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion, interop, coldfusion-8

I am modifying some CF8 code that uses the cfobject tag to do interop with .NET. Currently, it's targeting .NET 2.0 assemblies. Without upgrading CF, is there a way to get it to interoperate with higher versions of .NET (e. g. v4.0)? What, if anything, will I have to do?

Comment: I think you just have to install the version you want to use then uninstall and reinstall the .net integration service.

Comment: So to your knowledge there is no maximum .NET version?

Comment: IIRC, the max for CF8 is v3.5.

Comment: @Travis may have missed one step.  Somewhere along the line you have to produce something in .net using the higher framework and then try to access it with CF.

Comment: @Leigh do you know where that's documented?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion - Sorry, I do not remember where I read that offhand. Maybe poke around adobe's site (release notes and such) I just remember that v4.0 support was not added until CF9.0.1.

Comment: The most definitive reference I could find was the JNBridge docs ie `cf_root\jnbridge`. (JNBridge is bundled with CF and used for .NET interop). ColdFusion 8 uses JNBridgePro v3.1 which *".. supports all the .NET 2.0/3.0 features .. and will also work with .NET Framework 3.0 "*. ColdFusion 9 includes JNBridgePro v5.1 which [*"..supports multi-targeting toward .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0"*](http://www.jnbridge.com/jn/blog/2010/04/26/jnbridgepro-5-1-released/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From the comments ...)

[JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/) is bundled with CF and used for .NET interop. AFAIK, support for v4.0 was not added until CF 9.0.1. The most definitive reference I could find on this was the JNBridge docs ie `cf_root\jnbridge`:

- ColdFusion 8 uses JNBridgePro v3.1 which ".. supports all the .NET 2.0/3.0 features .. and will also work with .NET Framework 3.0 ".
- ColdFusion 9 uses JNBridgePro v5.1 which ["..supports multi-targeting toward .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0"](http://www.jnbridge.com/jn/blog/2010/04/26/jnbridgepro-5-1-released/).